# Create a list from the debug.log menu

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was thinking like
`public static List<string> debug = new list<string>(); debug.add("debug.log menu item 1");`
But I don't know how to do this van someone help

Nothing I have tried has worked Nobody has anything that works

Comment: Whats wrong with what you have

Comment: I asking if there is a command for debug.log menu item 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean you want to keep track of any logged messages you can attach a listener to e.g. [`Application.logMessageReceivedThreaded`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-logMessageReceivedThreaded.html)

```
private List<string> logs = new List<string>();

// Start is called before the first frame update
private void Awake()
{
    Application.logMessageReceivedThreaded += HandleLog;
}

private void OnDestroy()
{
    Application.logMessageReceivedThreaded -= HandleLog;
}

private void HandleLog(string content, string stacktrace, LogType type)
{
    logs.Add($"{type} - {content}\n{stacktrace}");
}
```

Obviously this will not allow to access any logs previous to attaching the listener ;)